# CSS: last-child of parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

`:last-child` works great when all of the "children" elements are the same (ie: all `<p>`'s or all `<li>`'s and the rule is applied to that type of child.

But how can I use CSS to select the last "child" element inside a parent which contains varying elements?

For instance, in this example, how could I apply a rule to the `.parent` to select the last object inside of it (the `div`)?

```css
.parent:last-child {
  background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  
  <p>First child</p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Second child" />
  <div>Third child</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: The rule you have is looking to select an element with the class `parent` that *is* the last child of some other element. Add a space between them.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Or just `.parent>:last-child` (your selector will match body)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use `.parent > *:last-child` or just `.parent > :last-child`

> An asterisk (*) is the universal selector for CSS. It matches a single
>   element of any type. Omitting the asterisk with simple selectors has
>   the same effect.

```css
.parent > *:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>First child</p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Second child" />
  <div>Third child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i wonder why it does not work when used like `.parent>:last-child` ??